# typescript definitions for mongodb not working?

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

everybody, what I must install for `mongodb` to  work in angular 4?
in my angular 4 project `db` is object of client of `MongoClient` class as this code:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, client) => {
            // Client returned
            var db = client.db('test');});
```

when I write `db.collection()` inside this code:

```
let db = DbClient.connect();
      db.collection();
```

in `app.module.ts` file I get this error:

```
"[ts] Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'void'."
```

where DbClient is class defined in my database file.
in this project I have `nodejs: 8.10.0` `mongodb version 2.2.33` and `@type/mongodb: 3.0.9`, this version of `mongodb` was 3.0.5 I have downloaded older version after search for solution but still not working yet.
please anybody can help me to solve this error?

Comment: I think you should pass collection name. db.collection('test');

Comment: thanks for replay, I think when the error is about argument I must get `Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0`, I tried to give the name but not solved. @Krishna

Answer (score 3):

`DbClient.connect();` connects the variable `DbClient`, and returns nothing. So when you try to write `let db = DbClient.connect();`, TypeScript correctly alerts you that `db` is a void variable with no methods.

I think you want:

```
DbClient.connect();
DbClient.collection();
```

Or

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, client) => {
    // Client returned
    var db = client.db('test');
    db.collection();
});
```

Comment: then how I can use the variable db in another class or file in the same project? if not returned any thing?